# how to pass param address to a function in lua

Tags: ios, lua

I use wax framework in my ios project.

I want to call objective-c method in lua,this is the method define:

```
- (BOOL)scanUpToString:(NSString *)string intoString:(NSString **)value;
```

You can see,second param is (NSString **) type, if I call this method in lua , how to write code?

I write lua script,code like this:

```
function method(obj)
local html="<some text>"
graphDataScanner = NSScanner:scannerWithString(html)
graphDataScanner:scanUpToString_intoString("abc",&result)

return result
end
```

when I run code,get error message:

> unexpected symbol near '&'
>   Lua panicked and quit: attempt to call a nil value

How to pass var's address to cocoa function?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, `local _, result = graphDataScanner:scanUpToString_intoString("abc")`